# Comment timestamp sequence

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, timestamps

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393096/display-jtable-with-javafx/32396344#comment52704993_32396344) to this recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32396344/230513), a user asked for clarification, and I responded. Oddly, my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393096/display-jtable-with-javafx/32396344#comment52704937_32396344) bears a timestamp *exactly* [five minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) *before* that of the incipient [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393096/display-jtable-with-javafx/32396344?noredirect=1#comment52704993_32396344). The user appears to have been editing the comment while I composed my response. Is this a minor glitch in the matrix or a serious bug that will be exploited by charlatans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the rough timeline:

- The OP commented on your answer (2015-09-06 02:31:41Z)
- OP deletes the comment (2015-09-06 02:32:47Z)
- You responded to this (now deleted) comment (2015-09-06 02:35:55Z)
- OP writes a new comment (2015-09-06 02:40:55Z)

So, you responded to the first comment when it was deleted and while the OP was writing a new comment.

Comment: Ah, thank you; that's exactly what I wanted to know. I infer that the five minutes was a coincidence.

Comment: So I'd say status by design, since it can be easily "reproduced" (or just retag to [tag:support] where no status tag is required :))